# Docker windows --network=host analog

Tags: docker, docker-network, docker-for-windows

I want to run mongodb inside docker container (without installing it on host machine) and work with it locally.

For linux I do:

`docker run --network=host mongo`

and all works as I want. I am able to connect to mongodb which runs on `localhost:27017`.

But when I do the same on Windows 10 machine, I can't connect to `localhost:27017` from host machine. When I run command as above, in console I see that mongodb is running and waiting for connections. But I can't connect from windows host.

So, how to make it work?